# dplyr 's chain is giving wrong result

Tags: r, dplyr

I am experimenting with below code

```
Obj1 = 45
Obj2 = 66
Obj_list = list(Obj1 = Obj1, Obj2 = Obj2)
names(Obj_list) %>% .[. %in% ls()] 
## results a character vector with 0 length
```

I was expecting above code would return all names of `Obj_list`

Can someone points me to right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to use `ls()` to list the objects in the global environment then that must be specified; otherwise, it will refer to the environment in which `ls` is run.

```
names(Obj_list) %>% .[. %in% ls(.GlobalEnv)] 
## [1] "Obj1" "Obj2"
```